# Word mail merge document - set number of pages in header

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge

I have a Word mail merge document where I place "Page X of Y" in the header.  When I run my merge, I get Page 1 of 3 at the top of page 1, Page 2 of 3 at the top of page 2, and Page 3 of 3 at the tp of page 3.  This is expected.

I now find that I need to start the paging at page 2 as an insert will be inserted as page 1 at a later point in time.  So, I found the Word page setting where it allows me to specify the starting page number.  I set that to 2.  Now, I get Page 2 of 3 at the top of page 1, Page 3 of 3 at the top of page 2, and Page 4 of 3 at the top of page 3.

How can I have Word add 1 to the number of pages so Word will print Page 2 of 4, Page 3 of 4, and Page 4 of 4 at the top of the 3 pages?

My header looks like this:

```
Page {PAGE} of {NUMPAGES}
```

I need to get Word to compute NUMPAGES as NUMPAGES + 1.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
{NUMPAGES}
```

to

```
{={NUMPAGES}+1}
```

Where *all* the brace pairs {} have to be the special field codes braces you can enter on Windows Desktop Word using ctrl-F9, not the characters you can type on the keyboard.

(Or maybe in this case you could just change `{NUMPAGES}` to `4` ?)